# PhpSpreadsheet when using getNumberFormat Object of class could not be converted to string

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

The value of Cell C13 is: 01/02/2018 and i need to get same result on output but:

If using `$d_calib = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->getCell( 'C13' )->getValue();` the result is: `42010`

also if echo `$d_calib = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->getStyle( 'C13' )->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('d/m/Y');` the result is: `Object of class could not be converted to string` if i do `print_r` to it the result is out of memory.

Any suggestions to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(2)->getStyle( 'C13' )->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('d/m/Y');`

If you want to set a date format code in PHPSpreadsheet, then you need to set an **Excel** date format code, not a PHP date format code

Answer (score 0):

used:

```
    $value = $worksheet->getCell('C13')->getValue();
    $date2 = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Date::excelToDateTimeObject($value);
    echo $date2->format('d/m/Y');
```